# Context menu missing when right-clicking on top panel in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, panel, top, context-menu

I did a clean install of 20.04 a couple of days ago and have been customizing my machine since then. When I right-click on the top panel, the context menu doesn't appear. I am used to using earlier versions of Ubuntu and adding apps to the top panel. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: In a default install of Ubuntu 20.04 there is no such thing.. your previous versions might be different..

Comment: UnKNOWn: thank you for your reply. However, please note that on the first day that I installed 20.04 I was able to access the context menu for the top panel. Then, after two days, it no longer appeared. I assume that one of the tweaks I made disabled the right-click context menu for the top panel. I want to know how to re-enable it. Anyone else have any assistance?